# iOS Cache UIImage between sessions

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I have an `UIImageView` that displays an user's Facebook photo. I download the image with `AFNetworking` and it is caching the image while the app is open.

What I want to know is if there is any built-in method that would allow me to keep the image saved on the device and use it in further sessions if there is no Internet. I know I can download the image and save it to the device manually, but I was wondering if there is already something built-in for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With sessions I'm assuming you mean when the app is closed (quit) and re-opened later on? If so, then there's nothing built in that can do that for you and you'll have to store it somewhere locally yourself.

Comment: Ye that was exactly what i wanted. Make the system save the Image even if the app closes, and update it when there is an internet connection

Answer (score 0):

There are several libraries available
try  [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

The idea is simple

Imageview ask for an image from url from image cache manager, the manager provide image if it has or download from server, then save locally for a cache time period and provides the image.

Comment: does it save even if the cache closes? Because that is what i am looking for, and so far i could not find any lib that would provide that.

Answer (score 0):

You can have your own API which looks something like this and handle downloading and saving the image to the disk:

```
+ (void)getImageForId:(NSString *)idString completionBlock:(void (^)(UIImage *image))completionBlock
{
    // Code to load the Image from the disk.
    UIImage *cachedImage = [self.cache objectForKey: idString];

    if (cachedImage) {
        completionBlock(cachedImage);
    } else {
        // Your code to download the image again
        // Save the image to the disk
        // return the image
    }
}
```